# How to track periodic payments with PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I want to create a Webservice where companies can place their ad on my webpage. They have to pay money for the ad: periodically every month. I want to realize the payment with PayPal.

**But i have to track if the company has paid, and if not i want to deactivate the company-account on my website.**

> In my opinion, i have to check the date when someone paid to PayPal,
>   write the date in my Database and check one month later if the company
>   paid again.

I couldn't find anything on the PayPal API-Websites.

Can anyone help me or give me a good explanation how PayPal handle those things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal does provide API access to manage this through the [Recurring Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments). The doco has a description of the workflow required, but of particular interest to you would be [`GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails`](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails).

You could check the profile status or the date of last payment received to see if a payment has been made and act accordingly.